# Will old request direct killed or will request completed if i switch directory in IIS?

Tags: c#, iis

i am planning to do no downtime deployment on IIS, what i tried to do is, i create folder v1 and v2, when the iis pointing to folder v1, i copy and paste newer version on v2, so i switch the directory to v2, if that time there is a request on v1, will the v1 request will be direct terminated? or application pool will pending it to be complete?

Comment: yes you application will start again. and all pending requests will be terminated

Comment: @AliReza if the request is still executing what will happen

Comment: if you restart you IIS app  they will be terminated. there is a few seconds gap that handles pending requests but there is no guaranty.  probably some requests will terminated